# using row_number to return specific rows of query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012 & MATLAB. I have a table of 5 columns (1 char, 1 datetime and 3 floats).  I have a simple query shown below that returns the data from this table which contains over a million records - this however causes an out of memory error in MATLAB.

**simple query**

```
 select id_co, date_r, FAM_Score, FAM_A_Score, FAM_Score
 from GSI_Scores
 where id_co <> 'NULL'
 order by id_co, date_rating
```

So I was looking to breakdown the query select the data in batches of 250,000 records. I have just come across the ROW_NUMBER function which I added to my query, please see below. This numbers all the records for me. However I am having trouble selecting say records between 250,000 and 500,000. How do I do this?

**updated query**

```
  select id_co, date_r, FAM_Score, FAM_A_Score, FAM_Score, row_number() over (order by id_co) as num_co
 from GSI_Scores
 where id_co <> 'NULL' and num_sedol between 250000 and 500000
 order by id_co, date_rating
```

Comment: Have you considered using a cursor? I know they're supposed to be a no-no, but they're great for working with large amounts of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use a sub query or [Common Table Expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) (CTE).

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  --Your query
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE num_co BETWEEN 250000 AND 500000
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an sample example

```
 declare @t table  (ID INT)
 insert into @t (id)values (1)
  insert into @t (id)values (2)
   insert into @t (id)values (3)
  insert into @t (id)values (4)

  ;WITH CTE AS
  (
  select *,COUNT(ID)OVER (PARTITION BY ID  ) RN from @t

 )
 Select ID from CTE C WHERE C.ID BETWEEN 2 AND 4 
 ORDER BY RN
```

OR

```
;WITH CTE (select id_co,
                        date_r, 
                        FAM_Score,
                        FAM_A_Score, 
                        FAM_Score, 
                        COUNT(id_co) over (PARTITION BY ID  DESC) as num_co
                from GSI_Scores
                    where id_co <> 'NULL')
            Select C.d_co,
            C.date_r, 
            C.FAM_Score,
            C.FAM_A_Score, 
            C.FAM_Score FROM CTE C
            WHERE C.id_co between 250000 and 500000
            order by C.id_co, C.date_rating
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the OFFSET x ROWS FETCH NEXT y ROWS ONLY commands like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TempTable (
    TempID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    SomeDescription VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(TempID))

INSERT INTO TempTable (SomeDescription) 
VALUES ('Description 1'),
    ('Description 2'),
    ('Description 3'),
    ('Description 4'),
    ('Description 5'),
    ('Description 6'),
    ('Description 7'),
    ('Description 8'),
    ('Description 9'),
    ('Description 10')

SELECT * FROM TempTable ORDER BY TempID OFFSET 3 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY;
```